# I need to randomly remove half of the words in a string in java

Tags: java, string

Ok so I'm working on this code to blend humanities and STEM. I know very basic java code and so I'm currently trying to stick to String methods. I know using arrays may be easier but I'm not well learned in how to use them. So so far I've made code that counts the words in the string in order to determine how many words to remove (half of them). Next I need to figure out a way to randomly remove half of the words and return a new string, possibly with spaces replacing the removed letters.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class wordcount
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {

    System.out.println("Simple Java Word Count Program");

    String str1 = "Look, you want it you devour it and then, then good as it was you realize it wasn’t what you exactly wanted what you wanted exactly was wanting";

    String[] wordArray = str1.split("\\s+");
    int wordCount = wordArray.length;

    System.out.println(str1 + "");

    System.out.println("Word count is = " + wordCount);

    int wordCount2 = wordCount/2;


}
```

}

Comment: What question are you asking? Are you stuck on how to generate randomness or on how to remove items from your array?

Comment: Besides the really obvious "what exactly is your question" .. please read about java coding style guides. Class names start Uppercase, and you use CamelCase too ... and even when you are just starting: try to give helpful names to your stuff. Like: "str1" doesnt say anything about the intended use. Rename that to something like "fullSentence" or something alike, and all of a sudden it is very clear what it is about. And dont call something wordArray - the type of collection might change; so just call it "allTheWords" for example.

Answer (score 2):

I copied the array to an arrayList to then iterate through the list and delete random elements. I hope this is the type of answer you are looking for.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str1 = "Look, you want it you devour it and then, then good as it was you realize it wasn’t what you exactly wanted what you wanted exactly was wanting";

    String[] wordArray = str1.split("\\s+");
    ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(wordArray));

    int wordCount = wordList.size();
    int halfWordCount = wordCount/2;
    int tracker = 0; //counter for iterations in while loop

    Random random = new Random();
    while(tracker < halfWordCount){
        int randomIndex = random.nextInt(wordList.size());
        wordList.remove(randomIndex);
        tracker++;
    }
    System.out.println(wordList.toString());
}
```

Comment: I got a workingish result but I would love input and modifications. I also need a way to take input for the poem and to only do the "remove method" after a mouse click

Comment: Did my answer ever work for you? If so, could you please accept it?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.* ;
public class wordcount
{
public ArrayList<Integer> test(Integer[] array) 
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
           list.add(array[i]);
         return list;
    }
public ArrayList<String> testS(String[] array) 
    {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
           list.add(array[i]);
         return list;
    }
public static void main (String[] args) 
{

    System.out.println("Removing random words in a Poem Program");

    String str1 = "Sample Poem by Noah Eli Gordon: Look, you want it you devour it and then, then good as it was you realize it wasn’t what you exactly wanted what you wanted exactly was wanting";

    String[] wordArray = str1.split("\\s+");
    int wordCount = wordArray.length;

    System.out.println(str1 + "");

    //System.out.println("Word count is = " + wordCount);

    //System.out.println(wordArray);
    //String[] ret = wordArray;
    //for(String str : ret)
    //  System.out.print(str); 

    int wordCount2 = wordCount/2;

    Integer[] myIntArray = new Integer[wordCount];
    //for(int i = 0; i<wordCount;i++)
    //  myIntArray[i] = i;
    //for(int str : myIntArray)
        //System.out.print(str); 

    wordcount w = new wordcount();
    String[] wordArray2 = new String[wordCount2];

    for(int i = 0; i <= wordCount2; i++)
    {
        int rand = (int)(Math.random()*(myIntArray.length-1));
        ArrayList<Integer> list = w.test(myIntArray);
        list.remove(rand);
        myIntArray = list.toArray(myIntArray);
        ArrayList<String> listS = w.testS(wordArray);
        listS.remove(rand);
        wordArray2 = listS.toArray(wordArray);


    }
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(String s : wordArray2) 
    {
        if(s != null && s.length() > 0) 
        {
            list.add(s);
        }
     }

    wordArray2 = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);

    //for(int str : myIntArray)
        //System.out.println(str); 
    System.out.println();
    String[] ret2 = wordArray2;
    for(String str : ret2)
        System.out.print(str + " ");
}
}
```